# Why does QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl not exist?

Tags: c++, qt, media-player

I have modified the Qt [Media Player Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html), trying to get *QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl* for a crossfade effect.

Here is my code:

```
auto service = m_player->service();
auto cc = service->requestControl("org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayercontrol/5.0");
Q_ASSERT(cc != nullptr);
QMessageBox::information(this, "", cc->metaObject()->className());
QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl* control = qobject_cast<QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl*>(cc);
Q_ASSERT(control != nullptr);
```

The problem is, that when I request the control, a `nullptr` is returned. Does anyone know why?

I'm using Qt 5.11 on Windows with MSVC compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaservice.html#details) of *QMediaService* is explicit about how to obtain a pointer to the media service's *QMediaControl* implementation:

> `auto cc = qobject_cast<QMediaPlayerControl *>(service->requestControl("org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayercontrol/5.0"));`

So, in order to get `cc` as *QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl* change:

```
auto cc = service->requestControl("org.qt-project.qt.mediagaplessplaybackcontrol/5.0");
```

to:

```
auto *cc = static_cast<QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl *>(qobject_cast<QMediaControl  *>(service->requestControl("org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayercontrol/5.0")));
```

Comment: You're right, but i need the QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl. 
Simply requesting "mediaplayercontrol" returns DirectShowPlayerControl

Comment: @Fred, I would advice you to post an example with enough details to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Fred, you could also try to substitute `qobject_cast<QMediaPlayerControl *>` with `qobject_cast<QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl *>`.

Comment: Updated my original post with the link, and the exact code. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Thanks, it works. :) Although doesn't support gapless playback :/

Comment: @Fred, what do you mean by _doesn't support gapless playback_? Btw, if you like the answer, you might as well consider upvoting it.

Comment: I meant that calling QMediaGaplessPlaybackControl::isCrossfadeSupported returns false, and setting a crossfade interval has no effect.

Comment: @Fred, now I understand and that is indeed unfortunate. Also thank you for upvoting!

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)